# How to test a local bot with a test-bot in bot framework V4

Tags: node.js, testing, botframework

I know version 3 of botbuilder SDK used the npm [bot-tester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bot-tester) module to send messages to the local bot, but I don't know if this will work for the newer version because you cannot create a *UniversalBot* to create those kinds of tests.

I am using Botframework V4 with Node.js, Mocha testing module, and Yarn package manager. I have successfully setup the test environment so I just call `yarn test` and the basic assertions I make (e.g. `assert.equals(1,0,'this will not work);`) run without unintended errors.

How can I implement testing so that I can pass a simulated conversation flow? It would essentially be two bots chatting with each other with expected results from each conversation.

Comment: Did you download ngrok and put in Emulator Settings?

Comment: Based on what I am reading from docs, I don't need ngrok because I'm not worried about a firewall. See below for verbatim doc:


    Configure ngrok

If you are using Windows and you are running the Bot Framework Emulator behind a firewall or other network boundary and want to connect to a bot that is hosted remotely, you must install and configure ngrok tunneling software. The Bot Framework Emulator integrates tightly with ngrok tunnelling software (developed by inconshreveable), and can launch it automatically when it is needed.